# How to disable unique keys

Tags: postgresql

Is there a command to disable unique keys? I tried to use following command to disable all constraints to achieve that but it seems uniques are still enabled:

```
ALTER TABLE <tablename> DISABLE TRIGGER ALL;
```

Comment: You need to `drop` the constraints, e.g. `alter table ... drop primary key`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name the problem is i do not want to drop but disable.

Comment: What do you want to achieve?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe database I have to create has relationships between tables. Data there unfortunately is not consistent generally speaking. Means for instance for 1:M relation 1 should be unique but the values are coming duplicated ! In this case I want to make manual clean-up by my custom script. This script is reading all constraint relations between tables. Therefore to read those relations I need to have relational model but due to fact data is "bad" I need to disable constraints before data loading, then run my script.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to disable a `UNIQUE` or `PRIMARY KEY` constraint.

From the explanations in your comment, I'd suggest one of the following methods:

- Use `INSERT ... ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING` to ignore duplicate values.
- Load the data into a temporary table first, remove duplicates there, then add the result to the actual tables.

Comment: Such constraints are not implemented as triggers.

Comment: So if by this command not either uniques or  primary keys are disabled, so what exactly is disabled running that command in practice? What about foreign keys are they disabled via that command at least?

Comment: The command disables triggers and foreign keys (which are implemented with triggers).

Comment: ehh. Yes i was thinking about those options but i thought there is any way to dosable uniques :/